# update table in gtk

Tags: pygtk, gtk

I have window that contains a table on screen, now I want to attach a widget to that table I use

```
gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table), label, ...)
```

the function is correct and it runs without any error

but table does not respond to that line I mean there is no change on my table, I think I need something to tell that table update it self but how?

note= that line is inside a callback of a signal and I am sure that signal runs

note2= I do not want to destroy window for that

note3= I use gtk+ and pygtk

note4= I am sure I attach that widget to a correct position ( it is free)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you call `gtk_widget_show()` on `label` first?